# Show that the error term grows exponentially - analysis

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I obtained the following difference equation to approximate the solution to a differential equation: $y_n = (1-\lambda h)^n$. We want this to tend to 0.

I have worked out that happens for $0 < \lambda h < 2$.

Now I have to show that if $h> \frac{2}{\lambda}$, the error term $y_n - \phi (x_n)$ grows exponentially. Here is my attempt:

$$|(1-\lambda h)^n - 0| < \varepsilon$$ $$ -\varepsilon < (1-\lambda h)^n < 
\varepsilon$$ $$\varepsilon^{\frac{1}{n}} > \lambda h - 1 > -\varepsilon^{\frac{1}{n}}$$ $$h < - \frac{1-\varepsilon^{\frac{1}{n}}}{\lambda}$$ and since we are looking at $h> \frac{2}{\lambda}$, we have $$ \frac{2}{\lambda} \geq -\frac{1-\varepsilon^{\frac{1}{n}}}{\lambda}$$ $$\varepsilon \geq (-3)^n $$ which grows exponentially as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Is this correct?

Comment: No, the last line of the first block is not a conclusion from the previous lines.

Comment: @LutzL How would I approach this then :(

Comment: Just use that the base $λh-1$ is greater than $1$.